# Why I can't float the div around the paragraph?

Tags: html, css

I can't for the life of me figure out how to make the div text go next to the paragraph text!! Like so:
........ paragraph text paragraph text div text div text ........
I want divs to be next paragraphs like they are in one text. Please help me with that!!

HTML:

```
<p><a href="#">paragraph text</a>, <a href="#">paragraph text</a>, <a href="#">paragraph text</a>, <a href="#">paragraph text</a>, <a href="#">paragraph text</a>, <a href="#">paragraph text</a>, <a href="#">paragraph text</a>, <a href="#">paragraph text</a>, <a href="#">paragraph text</a>, <a href="#">paragraph text</a>, <a href="#">paragraph text</a>, <a href="#">paragraph text</a>, <a href="#">paragraph text</a>, <a href="#">paragraph text</a></p>

<div><a href="#">div text</a>, <a href="#">div text</a>, <a href="#">div text</a>, <a href="#">div text</a>, <a href="#">div text</a>, <a href="#">div text</a>, <a href="#">div text</a>, <a href="#">div text</a>, <a href="#">div text</a>, <a href="#">div text</a>, <a href="#">div text</a>, <a href="#">div text</a>, <a href="#">div text</a>, <a href="#">div text</a>,</div>
```

CSS:

```
p {float:left;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lmk9s/519/

Comment: I'm confused. What do you mean by div text next to the paragraph text?

Comment: Sorry! Like this: ........ paragraph text paragraph text div text div text ........

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just use

```
display: inline
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmk9s/520/)

Comment: @captinmajid div by default is a block element. You can use display: inline as above to change the behaviour

Comment: Thank you Baconbeastnz, this works!! Thank you Oscar Siauw  for explaining :)

Comment: Haha no problems! bet that would have been annoying ;). Please accept answer if you are happy with it.